# Error inserting data into mongodb using robomongo

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

So this is my original data:

```
{
"_id" : "AHRLArFtRRWLp6knp",
"name" : "BlueCorp Steel inc.",
"subEnd" : ISODate("2017-04-21T14:00:00.000Z"),
"type" : "Enterprise",
"visions" : [ 
]
}
```

Now when I try to edit it, to make it so that I get this:

```
{
"_id" : "AHRLArFtRRWLp6knp",
"name" : "BlueCorp Steel inc.",
"subEnd" : ISODate("2017-04-21T14:00:00.000Z"),
"type" : "Enterprise",
"visions" : [ 
    {
        "refId" : 0,
        "order" : 0,
    }, 
    {
        "refId" : 1,
        "order" : 1,
    }
]
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to parse JSON:
First character in field must be [A-Za-z$_], at (10, 9)
```

Its roughly pointing to the "},"

Can someone please help me? Idk why im getting this dumb error, where adding an array should be a trivial thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, remove the extra commas in

```
{
    "refId" : 0,
    "order" : 0, // <-- remove
}, 
{
    "refId" : 1,
    "order" : 1, // <-- remove
}
```

so that becomes

```
{
    "refId" : 0,
    "order" : 0
}, 
{
    "refId" : 1,
    "order" : 1
}
```